# GoLang How to load nested objects using GORM

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

Hi let's say that I have 3 Structs in the following format

```
type Employee struct {
  Id int
  Name string
  CompanyId int `gorm:"column:companyId"`
  Company Company `gorm:"foreignKey:CompanyId"`
}

type Company struct {
  Id int
  CompanyName string
  OwnerId `gorm:"column:owner"`
  Owner Owner `gorm:"foreignKey:OwnerId"`
}

type Owner struct {
  Id int
  Name string
  Age int
  Email string
}

func (E Employee) GetAllEmployees() ([]Employee, error) {
  Employees := []Employee
  db.Preload("Company").Find(&Employees)
}

// -- -- There response will be like

[
  {
    id: 1
    name: "codernadir"
    company: {
      id: 5
      company_name: "Company"
      owner: {
        id 0
        Name ""
        Age 0
        Email ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

here I'm getting Owner values with the default values.
the given examples are for describing what I'm trying to reach.

I need a way how to load the Owner struct with its values when I load the Employees?

any suggestions will be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: As I understand, you can use something like this `db.Preload("Company.Owner").Find(&Employees)`

Comment: @nohattee yes brother you are right, this is what I found as a solution 2 days ago, thanks for sharing your knowledge, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I found as a solution to load the nested objects from embedded structs

```js
db.Preload("Company").Preload("Company.Owner").Find(&Employees)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gorm:"embedded"` tag:

```
type Employee struct {
  Id int
  Name string
  CompanyId int `gorm:"column:companyId"`
  Company Company `gorm:"embedded"`
}

type Company struct {
  Id int
  CompanyName string
  OwnerId `gorm:"column:owner"`
  Owner Owner `gorm:"embedded"`
}

type Owner struct {
  Id int
  Name string
  Age int
  Email string
}
```

Comment: ok, brother, this will mix them together, and how to load the Owner struct from the Employee struct?